Which English version of Psalm 121:2-3 expresses the Psalmist's intent best?
We read in Psalm 121:3-4 ( NKJV):

He will not allow your foot to be moved;
He who keeps you will not slumber.
Behold, He who keeps Israel
Shall neither slumber nor sleep.

Generally, the words 'sleep'and 'slumber' are used as synonyms, the latter frequently finding place in poems. Be that as it may, what is the purpose of stating ' neither slumber nor sleep' ? A clue could be found in certain vernacular versions which use the phrase ' doze off' in place of slumber. Now, a sentinel could doze off while  on duty,
standing up! Off duty, he sleeps lying down. Dozing off , a momentary sleep albeit not deep, diverts his attention making himself and those he is supposed to protect,vulnerable.
<  That said, a  better composition of Verse 4 would be ' neither doze off nor sleep' . I am however, not sure if 'doze off' is a refined way of expression in so far as Biblical language  is concerned. My question is:Which English version of Psalm 121:3-4 conveys the intent of the Psalmist best ?

The two operative verbs in Ps 121:4 are:

נוּם (num) = to be drowsy or slumber, Ps 76:5, 121:3, 4, Isa 5:27, 56:10, Nah, 3:18.
יָשֵׁן (yashen) = to sleep, eg, Gen 2:21, 41:5, Lev 13:11, 26:10, Deut 4:25, Judges 16:19, 1 Sam 26:12, 1 Kings 19:5, Job 3:13, Ps 3:5, 4:8, 13:3, 121:4, Prov 4:16, Eccl 5:12, SS 5:2, 7:9, Isa 5:27, Jer 51:39, 57, Eze 34:25, Hos 7:6.

Both are uncontroversial verbs whose meaning is undisputed.  They are always translated literally.
This distinction in meaning in Ps 121:3 &4 appears that God, our protector, neither dozes/slumbers nor sleeps.  That is, God's protection of Israel is unrelenting because God is always fully alert.  The amplified Bible attempts to make this clearer by offering:

Behold, He who keeps Israel Will neither slumber [briefly] nor sleep
[soundly].

Almost all English translation offer something almost the same as

... will neither slumber nor sleep.

Thus, the use of these two verbs in synthetic parallelism is a perfect example of Hebrew poetic repetition to add emphasis.

Job 33:14-16 does not differentiate between the terms :  "Indeed God speaks once, Or twice, yet no one perceives it. 15 In a dream, a vision of the night, When deep sleep falls on men, While they slumber in their beds, Then He opens the ears of men, And seals in their discipline

+1  I would add that the Psalms and other biblical poetry make frequent use of reiteration and repetition to emphasize a concept. e.g. Psalm 22:24

@DanFefferman - many thanks - good point.  I will add as you suggest.


Psalm 121:3-4
אַל־יִתֵּ֣ן לַמֹּ֣וט רַגְלֶ֑ךָ אַל־יָ֝נ֗וּם שֹֽׁמְרֶֽךָ ׃[3]
הִנֵּ֣ה לֹֽא־יָ֭נוּם וְלֹ֣א יִישָׁ֑ן ומֵ֗ר יִשְׂרָאֵֽל ׃[4]
[3] μὴ δῷς εἰς σάλον τὸν πόδα σου, μηδὲ νυστάξει ὁ φυλάσσων σε.
[4] ἰδοὺ οὐ νυστάξει οὐδὲ ἐξυπνώσει ὁ φυλάσσων τὸν Ἰσραήλ.
[3] He will not let your foot be moved; he who keeps you will not
slumber.
[4] Behold, he who keeps Israel will neither slumber nor sleep.

יָ֭נוּם=yanum=νυστάξει=slumber
יִישָׁ֑ן=yishan=ἐξυπνώσει=sleep
The first one we have fewer surviving examples of. In Psalm 76:5, the same two words are used: נָמ֣וּ שְׁנָתָ֑ם, but with the 'sleep' in a nounal form as the object of the 'slumber'. So what we are probably looking at is a distinction English doesn't possess: between the process of falling to sleep, and the end result of sleep.
Slumber is an outright archaism. It's supposed to mean a light state of sleep, but people think it means a deep state of sleep.
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slumber&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3
For example in this fascinating-looking YA comic book, "Slumber" is referring to a sufficiently deep sleep that you can set an entire Isekai story in it
https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Slumber_5/zPl6EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22slumber%22&printsec=frontcover.

Questions of the form "which translation expresses the original best" invite the answer "nope". That isn't something translations do.
The major translations on Biblehub (https://biblehub.com/psalms/121-4.htm) mostly stick to the ghastly archaism "slumber" but that's only because they don't know what else to do with it. The living language of English decided 200 years ago that it had one word too many for sleeping and it was going to dump the less common two-syllable one. Can't be carrying dead weight, right? Philological forces to contend with, what?
That leaves some dialects supplying dialect-idiom stopgaps. So we have "forty winks" and "getting some kip" and "catching some Zs" and "nodding off" and so on. Which the Imperial language immediately crushes into the lower mode of our speech.
A couple of the major bible translations have resisted: CEV has "doze" ISV has "take naps".
And the OP seems to be erring on the side of the Imperial master-language.
But English doesn't do these things in pursuit of refinement: it does them to keep its conquered language-families buying dictionaries and needing elocution lessons to gain employment.
CEV is designed for a lower reading-level, but to doze off is the gradual biological-physical process that יָ֭נוּם seems to refer to (going by the one useful example in Psalm 76). And it can be a noun: a doze.
And it's not really any less refined than any of the other barbarian grunty-noises we customarily utter up here in Ultima Thule.
The LXX's gloss νυστάξει is, nicely, that thing we do in the night (=νύξ). One isn't necessarily asleep yet (cf. Aristophanes Bird 639) or if they are it's a light sleep. So that supports all the above.

Aristophanes Birds, 639
Ἔποψ: καὶ μὴν μὰ τὸν Δί᾽ οὐχὶ νυστάζειν ἔτι ὥρα 'στὶν ἡμῖν οὐδὲ μελλονικιᾶν,
ἀλλ᾽ ὡς τάχιστα δεῖ τι δρᾶν
The Hoopoe-Bird: By Zeus! it's no longer the time to delay and loiter like Nicias;
let us act as promptly as possible....


Thanks FelixLXX, for the scholarly inputs. CEV speaks of fixing and feeling drowsy. But then, feeling drowsy does not mean sleeping ,does it ? To me, the psalmist wants to say that your watchman is 24X7 on duty with absolute concentration on your safety. He does not doze off while standing, not does he go to sleep while lying down to rest. Sadly, some versions use only one of the two phrases, namely : ' does not sleep

Please read ' dozing' in place of ' fixing' in the first line of my Comment .  Thanks.
